# Как правильно склонять женский ник?

Tags: склонение, ономастика

Ситуация такая. Есть у меня в постоянных читателях блога очень хорошая девушка с ником Осколок Эха. Но, когда я о ней кому-то говорю, никогда не знаю, как правильно склонять ее ник и склоняется ли он вообще?

Comment: Ник красивый, чувствуется, что девушка с фантазией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Случай любопытный...
С одной стороны женские андронимы, заканчивающиеся на согласную, склоняться не должны. 
С другой - общий принцип русского языка склонять всё, что только можно склонять. В том числе и "мужские" женские ники.

Пожалуй, и то и другое будет правильно. Категорически я бы отверг только идею склонять сочетания по образцу Джейн Фонда: Осколок Эха, Осколок Эхи, Осколок Эхе, и т.д.

Выбор же между склонением и несклонением, думаю, предопределяется тем, как вы используете сам ник. Если в женском роде: "Осколок Эха сказала", то склонять не надо: "Сказал (кому?) Осколок Эха", "Написано (кем?)Осколок Эха" и т.д. Однако для исключения двусмысленности часто придется добавлять "пользователю", "пользователем",и т.д.

Но если "Осколок Эха сказал", то и "Сказал (кому?) Осколоку Эха", "Написано (кем?)Осколком Эха".

Хотя, повторюсь, случай весьма спорный.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что вы вполне можете склонять  её имя по 2 типу склонения, как существительное мужского рода с нулевой флексией в именительном падеже. *Осколок Эха, Осколка Эха, Осколку Эха* и т.д. Называют ведь девушек АНГЕЛОМ, например, и ничего необычного в этом нет. *Целую моего ангела Анечку.*
Осколок Эха сказала (пришла, почувствовала) и т.д. Сказуемое при этом имени употребляем уже в форме женского рода.
Добавлю. Проблема может возникнуть с винительным падежом: *люблю Осколок Эха* (осколок ведь неодушевлённое существительное)? Звучит странно. В этом случае придётся добавить слово ДЕВУШКУ или сочетание ДЕВУШКУ ПО ИМЕНИ: люблю девушку по имени Осколок Эха.

Comment: Я не вижу проблем с винительным, отличных от проблем общих. Неодушевлённые существительные, используемые как клички или прозвища приобретают одушевленность. Видел Кирпича, привязал Щарика и проч. 
Соответственно, мужской ник будет иметь флекчию одушевленного: видел Отголоска сна. Никаких проблем. 
Вопрос только в том, как поступать  женским ником подобного рода.